# download html attribute does not rename the file using external URL

Tags: html

I am trying to rename a file when downloading it from `<a>` tag.

Here a simple example:

```html
<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/440u9.png" download="stackoverflow.png">Download Stackoverflow Logo</a>
```

As you can see, it never downloads the file with `stackoverflow.png` name, it does with default name though.

Nevertheless, if I download the image and tried to do the same with a local route, it renames the file properly.

Another example:

```html
<a href="./images/440u9.png" download="stackoverflow.png">Download Stackoverflow Logo</a>
```

The example above works properly.

Why `download` html attribute only works using local routes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attribute `download` [works only for *same origin* URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

By the way, you really should learn to use proper terminology, or else people won't understand you:

- `<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/440u9.png" download="stackoverflow.png">` is a *tag*, specifically, an *opening* tag;
- `download` is an *attribute*;
- `stackoverflow.png` is the *value* of the attribute;
- `https://i.stack.imgur.com/440u9.png` is a URL, sometimes called an URI or an address.
- The entire construction `<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/440u9.png" download="stackoverflow.png">Download Stackoverflow Logo</a>` is an *element*.

A "route" is something else entirely, and has no relationship with HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the points, I think now I have spelled it correctly. Please, if you see another terminology that is wrong, feel free to edit the question. Thanks again!

Comment: And thanks for the link, it seems that `same origin URLs` restriction was the problem that I faced.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any info of it, but seems like external resources aren't allowed renaming.

Have a look [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download), there's an example linking to google image and that doesn't work either - seems like the specs have changed along the way.

Answer (score 0):

This is a security measure applied to cross-origin download requests where the server hosting the download does not use HTTP headers to explicitly mark the file as being for download.

From [the HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#attr-hyperlink-download):

> If the algorithm reaches this step, then a download was begun from a
>   different origin than the resource being downloaded, and the origin
>   did not mark the file as suitable for downloading, and the download
>   was not initiated by the user. This could be because a download
>   attribute was used to trigger the download, or because the resource in
>   question is not of a type that the user agent supports.
>
> This could be dangerous, because, for instance, a hostile server could
>   be trying to get a user to unknowingly download private information
>   and then re-upload it to the hostile server, by tricking the user into
>   thinking the data is from the hostile server.
>
> Thus, it is in the user's interests that the user be somehow notified
>   that the resource in question comes from quite a different source, and
>   to prevent confusion, any suggested file name from the potentially
>   hostile interface origin should be ignored.